# add values to dropdown of product attribute

Tags: magento2

let say I made an attribute named `Cities`, how can I add options to this dropdown on the fly, considering there will be a hundred of more cities in my country.

Answer (score 0):

When you create an attribute programatically you can add source value into that attribute
`'source' => '<VendorName>\<ModuleName>\Model\Config\Source\Options',`

but If you create attribute from admin then you can create Options.php model class and fetch all cities from a custom city table and add into that attribute options array:

```
<?php

namespace <VendorName\<ModuleName\Model\Config\Source;

use Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\OptionFactory;

use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;

/**

* Custom Attribute Renderer

*/

class Options extends \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\AbstractSource
{

        /**

        * @var OptionFactory

        */

        protected $optionFactory;

        /**

        * @param OptionFactory $optionFactory

        */

        /**

        * Get all options

        *

        * @return array

        */

        public function getAllOptions()

        {

            /* your Attribute options list*/

            $this->_options=[ ['label'=>'Select Options', 'value'=>''],

            ['label'=>'Bestsellers', 'value'=>'0'],

            ['label'=>'Newest', 'value'=>'1'],

            ['label'=>'Hot', 'value'=>'2'],

            ['label'=>'Favourite', 'value'=>'3']

            ];

        return $this->_options;

        }

    }

}
```